# iPhone Web Application: Window.location doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications

I have added the required meta tags to my web app so that it can be launched on an iPhone from the springboard with no safari elements (address bar etc).
However, my login page works via JS, with the response coming back as JSON.

In Safari, when not launched as a web app, the redirect works fine (using window.location).
When launched as a web app, the redirect doesn't seem to work properly. The screen will refresh but be on the same page.

Is this a limitation of a web app or (as I suspect) am I doing it wrong?

This is the code that responds to the ajax post

```
genericPost: function (f, ajaxLoad) {
    if (ajaxLoad == undefined)
        ajaxLoad = true;
    var form = $(f);
    var data = form.serialize();
    var action = form.attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: action,
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.worked) {
                //navigate to the next required page
                //Notify.showMessage(response.message);
                if (response.redirect) {
                    if (ajaxLoad) {
                        Notify.showMessage(response.message, "ok");
                        var back = response.direction == "back";
                        $.mobile.changePage(response.redirect, "slide", back, true);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location = response.redirect;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Notify.showMessage(response.message, "ok");
                }

            }
            else {
                Notify.showMessage(response.message, "error");
            }
        },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function () {
            Notify.showMessage("Could not submit your form at the time. Please try again. Please try again", "error");
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the window.location was a red herring.
The issue was that ios seems to send a different user agent string when running full screen, one that IIS did not like.
IIS therefore decided that this browser did not support cookies or any of that stuff so the authentication token was failing.

This was fixed by adding a app_devices folder to my project and a .browser file.